# Starting python if function with an empty value possibility

Tags: python, if-statement, exception, empty-list

Automated stock bot in development here.

I'm trying to start an "if" function when an empty list value is returned as the argument, and end the script if a text (string?) value is returned. The reason for this is because I don't want to execute the if function if I currently have a trade open, only when I have no trades open. As far as I know the only modules from my broker's API(Oanda) useful to execute this task is one that outputs **[]** when I don't have a trade open. This was retrieved from the following list **{'positions': [], 'lastTransactionID': '4765'}** Part of me thinks what I'm trying to do is impossible, based on the research I've done, but I'm hoping someone has an idea. I put double asterisks around the important part of the script.

```
    from flask import Flask, request, abort
    import oandapyV20
    import oandapyV20.endpoints.positions as positions
    from exampleauth import exampleAuth


    # Create Flask object called app.
    app = Flask(__name__)


    # Create root to easily let us know its on/working.
    @app.route('/')
    def root():
        return 'online'


    @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
    def webhook():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            accountID, access_token = exampleAuth()
            api = oandapyV20.API(access_token=access_token)
            client=oandapyV20.API(access_token)
            r=positions.OpenPositions(accountID)
            x=client.request(r)
            **if x['positions']=='[]': #if empty execute if function, if not return 'okay'                      
            data = parse_webhook(request.get_data(as_text=True))
            sell=data['side']
            if data['side']=='sellEURAUD':
                exec(open("marketTPSLEURAUDv2sell.py").read())
            elif data['side']=='buyEURAUD':
                exec(open("marketTPSLEURAUDv2buy.py").read())
        else:
            return 'okay'**

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the qutos from empty list.
Should be like this-

```
if x['positions']==[]:
```

Comment: Holy crap if it was a snake it would have bit me. #classic Thanks Pritam!